# How do we specify migration targets for our site?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, migration-path-request

Users on Economics.SE (where I am a pro tem moderator) [have raised the issue that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345#96345) they are not able to specify which alternative sites within the SE network would be suitable when voting to close a question as belonging on another site.

As I understand it, [we can have a maximum of four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345#96345) sites for users to choose from. The list [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1535/108) reveals, in particular, that Money.SE receives a constant trickle of questions from Economics.SE. But how can we arrange for Money.SE to be added to the list close for migration targets?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/

Comment: @IͶΔ Thanks. Based on that post and out site stats, it looks like we are far short of the threshold beyond which a migration path is deemed worth while.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Historically beta sites haven't got migration targets, nor are they the target for migrations from other sites. So the simple answer is that you won't have these options because you're still in beta.

However, with the new gradual graduation and semi-permanent beta status that situation could (and perhaps should) get revisited.