# When voting to close and migrate to another site, how can I add another site?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, migration

When voting to close (or in such cases migrate) a question:

> Community specific
> What site does this question belong on?
>
> - expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com

Here one site is given, but I would like to suggest

- law.stackexchange.com

but there isn't any way to add this suggestion to the migration list.

Comment: I see you have a reasonable rep on Law.se so I assume you're familiar with the scope of Law.se. In general users suggest to migrate to site X while they have no account let alone knowledge of the scope of site X. Rejected migrations are a terrible waste of effort. Simply asking an OP to delete and re-post is more effective because they are the ones that can truly assess if their post is a good fit on site X.

Comment: Related question but not a dupe target [When should we consider adding a default migration path?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/273494)

Comment: @yagmoth555 No, not really. It only shows that the problem has existed for 9 years and as not been resolved. The present option, will in 99% of the needed cases, not be appropriate and therefore useless. Suggestions where it belongs, notifying an admin and adding a comment in one step would be more practical.

Comment: @rebe In this case the opposite is true.

Comment: Unfortunately experience is shown that most non-moderators, given the opportunity will attempt to migrate questions that are off-topic on the target site.

Comment: @RobertLongson This, unfortunately, leads the question to be closed (and thus 'forgotten'). Giving non moderators the opportunity to **suggest** where it should be placed with an alert to a Moderator and a comment in one step, would avoid this problem.

Comment: Too few moderators, or too many of us for that to be viable I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

The community migration list (i.e. the list of sites where question can be migrated without moderator assistance) only contains a small handful of sites of common migration points for that site. To add a site there, you need to post on the sites Meta and get community consensus. Generally sites are only added there if the migration route from site A to B is very popular.

A moderator can migrate to any site in the network:

> [image]

So, what you want to do is close with a custom comment, along the lines of:

> This belongs on site x because...

Then you can flag for moderator intervention and the moderator will hopefully migrate it to the other site.

Comment: If a non moderator could use that dialog, then a Moderator could be notified and a comment added in one step. For a non moderator the dialogue as it is now, is practically useless.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I agree fully.  Get rid of the migration options completely.